# PHP check for spaces infront of each operator

Tags: php, count, operator-keyword, space

Lets say i have a mathematic example

```
$example = 12 * 23 + 4;
```

i want to check if there is a space ' ' between each operator and the var -> else throw new expection
any ideas how to do it?
the only thing comming to my mind at the moment is to count all spaces and operators, but there must be a more efficiant way right?

Comment: try using regex, and is this code or something from your application? If it is code you can use a linter

Comment: spaces have no impact on the expression. so what's the purpose of doing this.?https://eval.in/861515

Comment: Uhh? What? So in your example the result would be 4 spaces? Perhaps you're looking for [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Comment: is this a user supplied string, that you eval or process in some way, or are you working on php source code (as shown in your question)?

Comment: my parser is not working if i dont use the white spaces, so i have to throw a error message

Answer (score 0):

no there is no other way to do that. Besides, why do you want to do that anyway?

Comment: Please don't misuse answer section for comments. Once you have enough reputation you can post comments.

Comment: my parser will not work if i dont have the white spaces so i have to check it and throw a error message